# I want my code to only allow inputs from 1-10

Tags: python-3.7

I'm just getting started with coding and took python as my first language. I decided to do this guessing number mini-project and I've gotten this far. It works perfectly but I want the user to only input a number between 1-10 and if it exceeds that or other input is given that isn't in that range. I want to print out a text.

I have been scouring the python documentation and haven't found anything, I'm pretty sure it's something pretty simple in the conditions but I can't figure out what it is.

Also if you see any way that this code could be improved please tell me I would love to know it

```
def game():
    mysteryNumber = random.randint(1,10)
    print("I just guessed a number.")
    inputByUser = input("Now choose a number from 1 to 10 : ")
    chosenNumber = int(inputByUser)

    if mysteryNumber == chosenNumber:
        print("You guessed it right.")
    elif mysteryNumber > chosenNumber:
        print("Too low. Try again buddy.")
    elif mysteryNumber < chosenNumber:
        print("Too high. Try again buddy.")
    else:
        print("The number you chose ' {} ' is not a valid number.".format(chosenNumber))
```

[Here is a picture of the full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOpEB.png)

EDIT: Nevermind I figured it myself I added this line of code after the first if statement

```
elif chosenNumber > 10:
    print("The number you chose ' {} ' is not a valid number.".format(chosenNumber))
    game()
```

It's not a perfect solution as it doesn't check within the range but I'll learn more about that down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve your if statement

```
elif (chosenNumber > 10) or (chosenNumber < 1):
    print("The number you chose ' {} ' is not a valid number.".format(chosenNumber))
    game()
```